# Do I need low-level minions?

Tags: evil-genius

In Evil Genius do I need to keep lower level minions once I've completed the Acts of Infamy that allow me to have high level minions?

I think I'm right in saying that only Valets can extinguish fires and only Technicians can repair things, so I need to have a few of those. But are there any tasks that can only be done by a Guard, Mercenary, Spin Doctor or Scientist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that only Technicians can repair your base (higher level science minions must consider it *beneath them*) and that only Valets can put out fires.  Additionally, only Construction Workers will build new rooms.  Therefore, you will want to keep some of each of these classes on hand in order to ensure your base is always operating at peak capacity.

There's only minor differences between the second tier science/military minions and their specialized third tier counterparts.  For instance, the Spin Doctor weakens Smarts while the Diplomat weakens Loyalty.  There's little in the way of monetary cost that would prevent you from training all of your minions up to a higher level.

A couple of things you should note, however:

- Certain Acts of Infamy on the world map require specific types of minion - it doesn't hurt to have at least a few of each class around, so that you don't have to train up some specifically should you need, say, a couple of Spin Doctors for an AoI.
- Training is costly in terms of *time* and *space* - you're tying up your high level minions for far longer to train each replacement minion.  Training them in a reasonable amount of time also requires you to have more training space, and space is always at a premium.  If the minion is going to be performing a task that could be performed by a lower level minion, why waste this additional effort?  Minions are expendable, so it's not really worth it to over-invest in their future.

Comment: Good point about the time taken to train minions, this is something I've overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need low level minions? Yes

Having construction workers let's you build rooms, place objects, etc. Also having a large base of construction workers allows you to have train more people into the other tiers faster than if you had only a few.

Valets are important for putting out fires in your base and technicians repair objects in your base to prevent explosions. Higher tiered versions of this minions won't do these jobs.

My general ratio was about 20 construction workers with *about* 26 in each type of minion class (military, social and science).

- For Military I go 5 -> 5 -> 8 / 8
- For Social I go 9 -> 5 -> 7 / 6
- For Science I go 9 -> 5 -> 7 / 6

I kept more valets and technicians around for the special tasks listed above.
Adjust the roster as you see fit. If your base is being attacked more, go with more military. If you want to research more, get more science minions.

Keep in mind, higher tiered minions can teach lower level minions, like a diplomat training a construction worker to be a valet, so keeping your minion roster higher tiered heavy is a good idea.

As a side note, there is a fan made mod called Evil Planet fan mod. [Link here](http://www.n1nj4.com/EvilPlanet/TheGame/modding.php) That increases your minion capacity to 150 amongst other things. You might want to check it out.

Source: [Evil Planet Wiki](http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Training: http://wiki.n1nj4.com/index.php?title=Training